# Need help coming up with a query or an alternate solution

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have a `table1` on `db1`. And I have another table `table2` on 'db2`. The`table2` is being used in the plsql procedure via dblink.

I have used cursor to fetch all the primary keys from `table1` such that my variable `ar_col` is list of PK's of `table1`.

Now I want to fetch all the values for those values from `table2`. In case, I don't have a value in `table2`, I should at least have pk from `table1` in my result.

I used following query but it is returning blank

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, 
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2@db_link t2
  ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
  WHERE t2.col1 IN (ar_col);
```

I want to use the result in a for loop, so i would be using bulk collect into on this query. the `ar_col` is array which holds all the pks of table1

P.S:
The definition of `ar_column` is

```
TYPE t_column IS TABLE OF TABLE_1.COLUMN_1%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
ar_column t_column;
```

P.S2: `ar_column` doesn't have all the primary keys, only selected based on some criteria.

Comment: If `ar_col` is just a collection of the values from `table1`, what purpose is there in using both the collection and the table in a SQL statement?  The query you posted also is not valid syntax but if you are getting a result with 0 rows, that implies that you're not getting an error which implies that the query you posted isn't the same as the query you're running.

Comment: ar_col is populated based on some criteria which is dynamic, the result is still pk from `table1` but few. So to sum it up, i first have to find specific primary_keys from table1. Then I have to find the respect records of those pk from table2.

Comment: OK.  So you're not getting "all the primary keys" then, right?  Is your query returning an error?  Because, as I said, the syntax you posted is not valid.  But you're not saying that you're getting a syntax error.  What is the definition of `ar_col`?

Comment: no syntax error. i trimmed down my original query so could be a typo. I am first trying to run it on plsql, and I am getting 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
select * 
  from (
         SELECT t1.col1, 
                t2.col1 t2col1, 
                t2.col2, 
                t2.col3, 
           FROM table1 t1, table2@db_link t2
          where t1.col1 = t2.col1 (+)
       )
 WHERE t2col1 in ( 
                   select thePrimaryKeyCol (what is the col name here)
                     from table1 
                 )
```

Comment: it works after a little modification. I have to add temporary table name before `where`