# how to use array as bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle11g, bind, bulk

I have following array, which will be populated based on some external criteria.

```
TYPE t_column IS TABLE OF TABLE_1.COLUMN_1%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
ar_column t_column;
```

Now, I want to use this `ar_column` into another cursor, how can i bind it ?

I am looking at something like `select * from table1 where column in (ar_colum[0],ar_colum[1] ...);` (its a pseudo code)

Comment: use parenteshis `ar_colum(0)`... and of course it has to be filled first

Comment: lol .. I want something dynamic. I can't type in all the array elements while writing the script.

Comment: I don't follow... Can you post just a sample example? And the portion of the code you are trying to use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help coming up with a query or an alternate solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008562/need-help-coming-up-with-a-query-or-an-alternate-solution)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question you asked a handful of minutes ago.

Comment: ^ no ... thats a different one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PL/SQL collections in SQL statements requires a few extra steps.  The data type must be created, not simply declared as part of a PL/SQL block.  Associative arrays do no exist in SQL and must be converted into a nested table or varray at some point.  And the TABLE operator must be used to convert the data.

```
create table table1(column_1 number);
insert into table1 values (1);
commit;

create or replace type number_nt is table of number;

declare
    ar_column number_nt := number_nt();

    v_count number;
begin
    ar_column.extend; ar_column(ar_column.last) := 1;
    ar_column.extend; ar_column(ar_column.last) := 2;

    select count(*)
    into v_count
    from table1
    where column_1 in (select * from table(ar_column));

    dbms_output.put_line('Count: '||v_count);
end;
/

Count: 1
```